# How to retrieve secret manager name from another template in CF?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Is it possible to import `secretmanager` name from another stack?

I tried this way in AWS CF, but it seems not working.

```
Environment:
        - Name: DB_USERNAME
          Value: !Join ['', ['{{resolve:secretsmanager:', {'Fn::ImportValue': !Sub 'NameOfRDSSecret'}, ':SecretString:username}}' ]]
```

I didn't find any documentation related to this issue. I am using now hardcoded values.

Comment: I'd expect Fn::ImportValue to work with *any* output from another stack in the same account, same region. Is the value of `NameOfRDSSecret` actually an exported output from another stack in the same region? What error message or symptoms are you seeing?

Comment: @jarmod The problem is my template is just drifted and I don't see any error messages. I used to use hardcoded values in the beginning and now my CF uses these values and mark the new template as drifted

Comment: it does not work even with hardcoded name from RDS

Comment: Instead of !Sub 'NameOfRDSSecret', try !Sub '${NameOfRDSSecret}'

Answer (score 2):

You added obsolete curly braces around your `Fn::ImportValue`.

Try the following:

```
Environment:
  - Name: DB_USERNAME
    Value: !Join ['', ['{{resolve:secretsmanager:', Fn::ImportValue: !Sub NameOfRDSSecret, ':SecretString:username}}' ]]
```